# Как вставить medium-draft на страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста как вставить [medium-draft](https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft) на HTML-страницу. [Пытался делать](https://jsfiddle.net/g8v0fq2k/3/) по этой [инструкции](https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft/wiki): в *head* разместил линк на CSS; и требуемые зависимости в том числе React, ReactDOM, Immutable и Draft.js. В *body* поместил скрипт как сказано в инструкции. Также в инструкции показан пример простого использования, пытался вставлять ничего не получается.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/medium-draft/dist/medium-draft.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/immutable@3.8.1/dist/immutable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/draft-js@0.10.5/dist/Draft.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/medium-draft@0.3.10/dist/medium-draft.js"></script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Моего скрипта, в смысле скрипт который указан в разделе Usage инструкции или какого? Документации react по диагонали прочёл, и в общих концепциях познакомился c node.js, npm, gulp и и webpack, но сознательно обхожу их стороной чтобы не заморачиваться, тем более как я понял судя по инструкции к medium-draft они не обязательны, и всё должно работать "из коробки".

Comment: скрипты каторые в head перенеси перед твоим скриптом

Comment: перенёс. а что дальше?

Comment: если не помогло то я уже не знаю я уже год как так нечего не подключаю только через npm и все отлично работает